# Visual Studio 2010 Find in Files, Appending Results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way (setting or extension?) to have the Visual Studio 2010 Find in Files feature append the search results (rather than replace them)?

I realize you can send the result to one of two result screens, but that is cumbersome, and wont work past two result sets.

Using SlickEdit in the past, It was nice to just append search results, and just scroll up.